# How do I fix the bug: "TypeError: firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function" in a Vue app with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using Vue to create a sign-up/sign-in page by implementing Firebase's client-side authentication system. I've already enabled the email authentication in my Firebase console, and the implementation of signing a user up was a success. However, for some reason, the function `firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail()` is giving the error `TypeError: firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function` in the console. The email I'm using is already present in the Firebase's Users data. The code is from a separate *Forgot Your Password* page, where I've already imported the relevant JavaScript files (firebase-auth.js, firebase-app.js, and vue.js).

Here's the code I've written:

```
<section class="columns" id="content">
    <div class="column content">
        <form @submit.prevent="sendPasswordResetEmail">
            <p>Please enter your e-mail if you've forgotten your password:</p>
            <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email"><br /><br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
const config = {
//Removed the values from config.
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
    el: '#content',
      data: {
        email: '',
    },

    methods: {
        sendPasswordResetEmail () {
            firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);
        },
    },
})
</script>
```

In addition to the error mentioned in the question, there's another error which shows up, which is `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function"`. I'm not sure what that means though.

P.S.: I've used Bulma for styling purposes, so the `columns` and `column` classes are from there, in case anyone was curious.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);`? Seems like you forgot to add `()` after auth.

Comment: Badum-tsss! That's right @AndréKool. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me. I forgot a pair of braces in the function I was calling. As André Kool pointed out in the comments, it was supposed to be `firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);`. I missed the parentheses after `auth`.
Thanks again Mr. André. I ought to up my copy-paste game up one notch.